# How can I have different backgrounds for columns in a Twitter Bootstrap datatable?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am using a Twitter Bootstrap datatable. I'm finding it hard to get documentation on styling them. I have 30 columns, some columns have data that can be edited, some fields cannot be edited. I need to highlight / change the background for all of the editable fields (which will be about 20 columns, and not all next to each other).

Does anyone know if this is possible? I know bootstrap has some pretty strict design, but I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: A 'datatable' or a table with data in it?  Is it a plugin or is it just Bootstrap for a table?

Comment: DataTables is a plug-in for the jQuery Javascript library. but i'm using it with bootstrap stuff. (bootstrap.datatables.css, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the colgroup structure:
- create a col element for each column in your table
- now you can set a class or an inline style for the editable columns

```
<table class="table">
<colgroup>
<col style="background-color: red;">
<col class="editable">
<col>
<col class="editable">
</colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Column heading</th>
            <th>Column heading</th>
            <th>Column heading</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
            <td>Column content</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: thank you for the link, but from what I see, they only tell you how to modify rows at a time, not columns at a time, which is what I was looking for.